# using AND operator in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cbxSelectAllPreventive"/> <label>Select All</label>
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
       <li ng-repeat="test in lists.Tests">
       </li>
    </ul>
```

Test is an array of complex objects having isSelected property.
I want to use the checkbox as SelectAll functionality. 
To do this , I need to supply ng-model to the checkbox, I can supply it as a method which checks in each of the tests and returns true/false. Is there any way to do this inline, without writing a method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only see a way to do it using a function on `ng-change`

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="cbxSelectAllPreventive" 
      ng-model="checked" ng-change="setAll(checked)"/>
...
$scope.setAll = function(isSelected){
    $scope.lists.Tests.map(function(el){
        el.isSelected = isSelected;
    })
}
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/geLLfLz3/)

EDIT:

For complete two-way connection between items' selection and check box the code will be a bit more complicated.

We will use an extra variable in `$scope` to reflect the label of check box. Don't forget to init the variable at controller creation

```
<label for="cbxSelectAllPreventive">{{selectLabel}}</label>
...
$scope.selectLabel = 'Select All';
```

`setAll` function should take care of setting this variable.

```
$scope.setAll = function(isSelected){
    $scope.selectLabel = isSelected ? 'Deselect All' : 'Select All';
    $scope.lists.Tests.map(function(el){
        el.isSelected = isSelected;
    })
}
```

And finally you definitely will have an option to select/deselect individual items. For this case you have to `$watch` your list. Mind the third parameter `true` which does deep comparison otherwise it won't "notice" changes inside objects.

```
$scope.$watch('lists.Tests', function(){
    var text = $scope.lists.Tests.map(function(el){ return el.isSelected; }).join();
    console.log(text);
    var allSelected = $scope.lists.Tests.every(function(el){ return el.isSelected;});
    var noneSelected = $scope.lists.Tests.every(function(el){ return !el.isSelected;});
    if(noneSelected){
        $scope.selectLabel = 'Select All';
        $scope.checked = false;
    }else if(allSelected){
        $scope.selectLabel = 'Deselect All';
        $scope.checked = true;
    }
    if(!noneSelected && !allSelected) {
       $scope.selectLabel = 'Undetermined'; 
// here set the check box to undetermined (third) state
    }
}, true);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/geLLfLz3/2/)

Comment: another add on question, how can I change text to select All/ Deselect all in the same scenario ?

Comment: In my opinion this will be not the only thing you will have to trace. Obviously you will have a mechanism to select individual items and it should be reflected too. You will have to build a [three-state checkbox](http://www.software-architects.com/devblog/2015/02/26/Tri-State-Check-Box-in-HTML-with-AngularJS-and-TypeScript) on your own. In my updated answer I give an idea when to trugger it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [ng-checkbox](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) is should do exaclty what

Comment: How exactly does it help to modify a list in scope without an extra function in `$scope`?